# Should I be re-initializing the whole model between loops of K-fold Cross-validation? And how do I do that?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I've been following a [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-convolutional-neural-network-from-scratch-for-mnist-handwritten-digit-classification/) on applying CNN to classify the MNIST handwritten numbers dataset.

I'm just a bit confused on one point in K-fold Cross-validation. The author of this tutorial mentions in [another tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/) that the model should be discarded each time the folds are swapped around. So to quote it:

> 1. Shuffle the dataset randomly.
> 2. Split the dataset into k groups
> 3. For each unique group:
>
>    - Take the group as a hold out or test data set
>    - Take the remaining groups as a training data set
>    - Fit a model on the training set and evaluate it on the test set
>    - Retain the evaluation score and **discard the model**
> 4. Summarize the skill of the model using the sample of model evaluation scores

Although in the CNN tutorial this is how the author applies K-fold validation:

```
def evaluate_model(model, dataX, dataY, n_folds=5):
    scores, histories = list(), list()
    # prepare cross validation
    kfold = KFold(n_folds, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
    # enumerate splits
    for train_ix, test_ix in kfold.split(dataX):
        # select rows for train and test
        trainX, trainY, testX, testY = dataX[train_ix], dataY[train_ix], dataX[test_ix], dataY[test_ix]
        # fit model
        history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_data=(testX, testY), verbose=0)
        # evaluate model
        _, acc = model.evaluate(testX, testY, verbose=0)
        print('> %.3f' % (acc * 100.0))
        # stores scores
        scores.append(acc)
        histories.append(history)
    return scores, histories
```

So the model is not being re-initalized with each iteration of the for loop. And we can see this in the chart plotting the loss at the end of each epoch (blue curve). Notice how the the curves get closer and closer to the axis.

[image: Cross Entropy Loss for training folds (blue) and the validation folds (yellow)]

So shouldn't the author be re-initializing the model between loops? And if so, is there a right way to do that in Keras without making a new model from scratch?

*Bonus:*
 The yellow line in the chart above is the loss of the validation fold. Why is its shape so different from that of the training loss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You and the author should use and should have been used `keras.backend.clear_session()` to fit your new model from scratch with the new split of your data set, but the author just wrote about the crossvalidation in general and he/she wrote:

> The models are then discarded after they are evaluated as they have
>   served their purpose.

So how do should you do it in your case:

```
def evaluate_model(model, dataX, dataY, n_folds=5):
    scores, histories = list(), list()
    # prepare cross validation
    kfold = KFold(n_folds, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
    # enumerate splits
    for train_ix, test_ix in kfold.split(dataX):
        # select rows for train and test
        trainX, trainY, testX, testY = dataX[train_ix], dataY[train_ix], dataX[test_ix], dataY[test_ix]
        # fit model
        history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_data=(testX, testY), verbose=0)
        # evaluate model
        _, acc = model.evaluate(testX, testY, verbose=0)
        print('> %.3f' % (acc * 100.0))
        # stores scores
        scores.append(acc)
        histories.append(history)

        # Here we do the reinitialization 
        keras.backend.clear_session()

    return scores, histories
```

The yellow validation line can be other shape, but we try to prevent to be different avoiding overfitting on training data.

Comment: Thanks! So you're saying that what's shown in my chart is an indicator of overfitting?

Comment: @AlexanderSoare Welcome, yes it can be but it depends on the size of the dataset as well. Because sometimes your validation data is not representative enough, if you have a small sample number.